# Vim Python completion

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

I'm having trouble with Vim and Python completion.
In fact I'm totally confused how does this work.

I have generic gvim 7.3, on windows 7 (with python/dyn)
I'm using SuperTab plugin, amongst many others, some of which
are python-specific, with following settings in vimrc:

```
au FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
let g:SuperTabContextDefaultCompletionType = "<c-n>"
```

I did not set PYTHONPATH enviroment varariable.

Completion works ok for system modules.

At first I thought that it isn't working at all for non-system
code, but that's not the case.
What is happening is best shown on following code:

```
import numpy.random   # if this line is commented completion in last line works

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, x_):
        self.x=x_

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def pr(self):
        print 'ok'

a=C(10)  # nothing changes if I put C() instead, even though it would be wrong
a.  # here is completion in question
```

Problem is that completion works (a.<tab> suggests getX and pr) if import line is commented. But it there is import numpy.random, completion brakes down.
Note: this import works normally when I run the code.

What are prerequisites for Python completion?
What's happening and what should I do to get completion working for Python.

As I am (relatively) new to Vim, any suggestion is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
It seems that the problem is in using a.b form in import. If I do from numpy import random, everything is ok. If this is reasonably easy to fix I would like to get a.b from to work too. But now that I know how to go around it that's not so important.

Are there more unusual problem like this one so that I know what's happening in the future?

Comment: I'm use rope-vim and it works well. Take a look also on [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode)

Comment: Have you tried `<C-x> <C-n>`, `<C-x> <C-p>` or just `<C-n>` and `<C-p>`? These completion work fine for me.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but why do you use getters instead of properties?

Comment: Did you raised the Bug Fix for this issue as it is easily reproducible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim autocomplete for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138039/vim-autocomplete-for-python)

Answer (score 30):

pythoncomplete is rather old and unmaintained.

Try to use Jedi: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim
It was originally an improved pythoncomplete, but is now much much more powerful!

It works for complex code:[image: completion]

And has additional features:
[image]

There is a list of all possible features:

- builtin functions/classes support
- complex module / function / class structures
- ignores syntax and indentation errors
- multiple returns / yields
- tuple assignments / array indexing / dictionary indexing
- exceptions / with-statement
- *args / **kwargs
- decorators
- descriptors -> property / staticmethod / classmethod
- closures
- generators (yield statement) / iterators
- support for some magic methods: `__call__`, `__iter__`, `__next__`,
  `__get__`, `__getitem__`, `__init__`
- support for list.append, set.add, list.extend, etc.
- (nested) list comprehensions / ternary expressions
- relative imports
- `getattr()` / `__getattr__` / `__getattribute__`
- function annotations (py3k feature, are ignored right now, but being parsed.
  I don't know what to do with them.)
- class decorators (py3k feature, are being ignored too, until I find a use
  case, that doesn't work with Jedi)
- simple/usual `sys.path` modifications
- `isinstance` checks for if/while/assert

Answer (score 5):

Python, being an incredibly dynamic language, doesn't lend itself to completion. There isn't any really good completion out there. It's easier to just live without it than to fight with all its problems, IMO. That said,  [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) really is fantastic, like neoascetic said.

Comment: Yes, python is dynamic, but you can also introspect everything about a running program as it is running, which would lend itself incredibly well to completion.

Comment: Yeah, running your program to get completion, sounds like a great idea.

Comment: Since this was posted I discovered jedi, and so did the other person two gave a better answer. It does static analysis and is wonderful.

Comment: I was only expressing the power of the interpreted language. I wasn't suggesting to actually run the code in order to obtain completions. Traversing an AST after compiling to object code could certainly be a way of providing functionality. Even loading a module to inspect what is available is a decent option as long as the module loading process doesn't produce unwanted side-effects.

Comment: Yeah. It's reasonable in some languages, but Python is not one of them, as loading any code can execute arbitrary code.